# summing up values in dictionary

Tags: numpy, dictionary, tuples, networkx

I am working with networkX which is a graph based library in python. I have truncated data here because it is just a list of dictionaries.

I want to sum up the number of triangles in a graph.

```
import networkx as nx
for i in graphT:
    print(nx.triangles(i))
```

This generates

```
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 2, 13: 0, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 1, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 5, 26: 1, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 1, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 4, 34: 1, 35: 3, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 2, 39: 1}
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 0, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 0, 18: 1, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 1, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 2, 34: 0, 35: 2, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 2}
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 2, 11: 0, 12: 4, 13: 0, 14: 3, 15: 4, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 1, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 3, 26: 2, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 1, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 1, 34: 1, 35: 2, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 2, 39: 2}
```

......

Now with that, I want to sum the values

for which

```
for i in graphT:
    #print(nx.triangles(i))
    for k, v in nx.triangles(i).items():
        #print(i.number_of_edges(), v)
        #print(jt.append(v))
        vi= v
        print(k, vi)
        break
```

which generates tuple of for key '0'. I have truncated data here with break statement.

```
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 1)
(0, 5)
(0, 2)
(0, 4)
(0, 3)
(0, 5)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 1)
(0, 4)
(0, 1)
(0, 8)
(0, 5)
(0, 2)
(0, 4)
(0, 3)
(0, 5)
(0, 6)
(0, 3)
(0, 3)
(0, 11)
(0, 7)
(0, 18)
(0, 9)
(0, 8)
(0, 4)
(0, 12)
(0, 22)
(0, 14)
(0, 23)
(0, 18)
(0, 2)
(0, 41)
(0, 8)
(0, 29)
(0, 13)
(0, 12)
(0, 53)
(0, 12)
```

How would I sum up values on this this tuple which is second element? If I use `sum(v)` or `sum(vi)` I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

***This gives me solution:***

```
j= [(sum(n for _, n in nx.triangles(i).items()), i.number_of_edges()) for i in graphT]
```

Comment: Can you clarify a point: do you generate the tuples specifically for the sum or do you need the tuples for some other purpose?

Comment: I will have to use the sum for finding probabilities later.

Comment: I understand you need the sum, but I am asking if you really need to print all those `(k, v)` tuples or if you only care about the sum over `v`

Comment: nx.triangles(i).items() is a dictionary. I need to sum up the values from this dictionary. That is where I got stuck. Say sum of v on on each graph 'i'

Comment: I would need the keys too

Comment: `nx.triangles(i)` can't be right.  (certainly I get an error in my version of networkx).  Networkx would have no way of knowing what graph to look at.

Comment: unless I suppose `graphT` is a list of graphs?  It helps to provide complete code (a [mcve]) to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: Yes it list of graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all of the values of a dictionary with `values`.  Then sum those.  So for this case:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(1000,0.05)
triangle_counts = nx.triangles(G)
triangle_sum = sum(triangle_counts.values())
number_of_triangles = triangle_sum/3
print(number_of_triangles)
> 20444.0
```

Note that each triangle is counted once per node, so I've divided by 3.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Here is what i ended up doing : j= [(sum(n for _, n in nx.triangles(i).items()), i.number_of_edges()) for i in graphT] from which I obtain all required values for Triangles and Edges. Actually trying to implement ERGM. If you have some knowledge of scratch level implementation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Offhand I don't know of anyone who has set up an ERGM package in networkx.  I keep hoping that someone will.  My knowledge isn't great enough to feel comfortable doing it, but perhaps I'll attempt it sometime in the future.